# Is it possible to deserialize into property rather than an object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Appologies if its already been asked, I could not find anything helpful to my situation.

I need to deserialize a JSON in a property of my object instead  of a whole object. The reason I am trying to do it, is that is simply generics.

I have the following situation

For instance I have

```
Class User 
{
   int UserId {get;set;}
   string Name {get;set;
}

Class Wanted : CustomClass
{
   User[] Users {get;set;}

   public override void Map(){ } 
   public override void Scan(){ }
}
```

My Json is:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "Josh"
  },
  {
    "userId": 5,
    "name" : "Martin"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to deserialize(+ generics) my JSON directly into my Wanted class instead of serializing into A and then assign it into Wanted ?

The goal is after the serialization I will have object with type Wanted and an array with 2 users in it.

Comment: `and then assign it into Wanted ?` Why do you **not** want to do that?

Comment: So you want to deserialize an array of `User`? Simply call `JsonConvert.Deserialize<User[]>(...)` and assign its result to `myWanted.Users`. Anyway I can´t see where you´re using generics.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sounds like OP wants to do `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Wanted>(...)` populating the `Users` property and returns an instance of `Wanted`

Comment: @phuzi exactly, thats my what I want

Comment: Did you try `JsonConvert.DeSerialize<Wanted>(myString)`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - yes I got Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException, if I do JsonConvert.DeSerialize<User>(myString) it works fine, but thats not what I want.

Comment: So why don't you just do; `new Wanted() { Users = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<User>(myString) };`? You don't serialize something "into a property". You deserialize something into an instance of some type and you set a property of some type to an object of some type. And where is your "generics" in this sample?

Comment: @mm8 how would I make it generic ? I am trying to achieve this with no hard coded values or types.

Comment: Then how should anyone know, that your string should deserialize to `Wanted`, and not e.g. to `CustomClass`? Or even another unrelated class that also has a `Users`-property?You *have* to provide that information somewhere.

Comment: "Generic" in what way? There is nothing generic about a `Wanted`.

Comment: Can you change the JSON?  You could wrap your existing JSON in an outer object `{  "users": [ ... ] }` and then you could deserialize into `Wanted`

Comment: @HimBromBeere Wanted is my desired  class. Its inheriting `CustomClass` which contains meta data from the RESTful call (in this case) and also each method can have its own mappers and etc.

Comment: @BrianRogers unfortunately, I cannot

Comment: That is clear. But imagine you have two classes that both derive from `CustomClass` and both have a `Users`-property. How should the serializer know which object to create? You have to provide that information.

Comment: Okay, will have to think about how to rephrase my question and probably open a new one. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON does not match the class you want to deserialize into, and you cannot change the JSON, you will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` to bridge the gap.

To make it work you'll need to introduce an interface `IHasUsers` which your `Wanted` class (or its base class) will need to implement:

```
interface IHasUsers
{
    User[] Users { get; set; }
}

class Wanted : CustomClass, IHasUsers
{
    public User[] Users { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you can make a generic converter which will instantiate the `Wanted` class (or any other class which implements `IHasUsers`) and populate the `Users` property:

```
class UserListConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T: IHasUsers, new()
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IHasUsers).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        T obj = new T() { Users = array.ToObject<User[]>() };
        return obj;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON like this:

```
Wanted wanted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wanted>(json, new UserListConverter<Wanted>());
```

Here is a demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/KL6Ok6

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Wanted` is "your desired class", there needs to be an instance of `Wanted` created somewhere. You might just as well create it yourself rather than having a derserializer do it for you. Once you have done this you can simply set the `Users` property to the deserialized data:

```
var wanted = new Wanted() { Users = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<User[]>(myString) };
```

You don't deserialize some data "into a property" without deserializing it to some object of some type first. Once you have done this you can then set the property to the object that contains the deserialized data.

There is nothing generic about `Wanted` here though and the deserializer cannot be supposed to figure out that it should create a `Wanted` or any other type unless you specify the type to derserialize the data to somewhere.

And there is no point of deserializing the data to a type defined at compile time if you don't know that the data matches this type. Then you might as well create an anonymous object or a dictionary of key/value pairs.

Comment: Okay, will have to think about how to rephrase my question and probably open a new one. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.json . Try below

```
 var files = JArray.Parse(YourJSON);
 var recList = files.SelectTokens("$").ToList();
 foreach (JObject item in recList.Children())
  {
    foreach (JProperty prop in item.Children())
      {
         string key = prop.Name.ToString();
         string value = prop.Value.ToString();
        // and add these to an array
      }
  }
```